# Check every CheckBox inside ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to Xamarin. I want to setup a ListView in Xamarin plus 2 buttons to check/uncheck every CheckBox inside the ListView to utilize the checked ones afterwards. Could you please tell me how to access these Checkboxes with kind of a foreach loop?

[image: Layout]

```
<ListView x:Name="countryListView" HasUnevenRows="true" ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        <MenuItem Text="Bla" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                        <MenuItem Text="Delete" IsDestructive="true" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Clicked="deleteCountry" />
                    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="5">
                        <controls:CircleImage HeightRequest="30" WidthRequest="30" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageURL}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                        <!--<Image Source="{Binding imageURL}" />-->
                        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="{Binding name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding capital}" />
                        </StackLayout>
                        <CheckBox x:Name="checkbox" IsChecked="false" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: You can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20684796/get-listviewitem-children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the IsChecked property of your checkbox to bool in your ViewModel and in OnClick event make it true or false. Don't forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged to refresh your UI.